# Question regarding badges

Tags: support, badges

Will a post with 10000+ views get a Famous Question (golden)badge automatically ? Or is there any other criteria present with it ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it should happen automatically. There may be a delay due to caching and whatnot, but generally you shouldn't have to do anything else.

If you think you should've received a badge and you didn't, let us know what question should've yielded a badge and we can look into it.

Comment: Ok. There was a delay . But I got the badge . Thanks .